# asp.net datalist doesn't recognize html tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I am new at asp.net and I am making an school application. I am at the point when i should adapt my page with template. I am using dataList as it could be integratet easily with template, but I am having a problem with html tags. When i put  inside  it doesn't recognize and doesn't shows any error or value.

```
 <HeaderTemplate>
         <section id="main" class="column">
          <article class="module width_full">
            <header><h3>Perditeso Artikullin</h3></header>  
              <div class="module_content">                      
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate> 
                <fieldset>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">Tema</asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTema" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Tema") %>'></asp:Label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblKeywords" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Keywords") %>'></asp:Label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblKategoria" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Kategoria_Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </fieldset>  
                <fieldset>         
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                </fieldset>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>  
                <fieldset>
                    <asp:TextBox style="width:500px;" ID="etxtTema" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Tema") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <asp:TextBox style="width:500px;" ID="etxtKeywords" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Keywords") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <asp:TextBox style="width:500px;" ID="etxtKategoria" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Kategoria_Id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                </fieldset>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate> 
        </div>      
        <footer>
            <div class="submit_link">
                <select>
                    <option>Draft</option>
                    <option>Published</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Publish" class="alt_btn">
                <input type="submit" value="Reset">
            </div>
            </footer>
        </article>
        </section>
        </FooterTemplate>
```

Console:

```
<section id="main" class="column" style="height: 553px;">
          <article class="module width_full">
            <header><h3>Perditeso Artikullin</h3>
                         </header>  
              <div class="module_content">                  
              </div>
          </article>
 </section>
```

Comment: Is the datalist bound to a data source?  ANd does that data source have data?  It'll only show content if it's bound to data...

Comment: yes it is bound to data because when i remove fieldset tags it diplays data. Only when try to put tags of template it doesn't shows anything